# Screen stopped recognizing the function within my primary prompt

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm using a custom command prompt that uses a custom function to display the current Git branch's name. The function and the PS1 are both in my .bash_profile:

```sh
# Defines a shell function: run "git branch" and extract branch name
parse_git_branch() { 
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
# Adds the above shell function to the command-line prompt when you're in a Git-tracked folder
export PS1="\W \[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$ "
```

The whole thing has worked seamlessly until today, including in Screen sessions created before today. Today, for some reason, Screen has stopped recognizing the custom function. In any new Screen session I create, each command prompt looks like this ("base" being the Conda environment):

```sh
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
(base) ~ $
```

The first line repeats before *every* prompt, which gets old pretty quickly. Sourcing .bash_profile within the Screen session doesn't change anything, whether or not I comment out the function and the PS1 line. It happens both in local Screen sessions and in sessions launched while SSHed into my university's HTC cluster submit server. Sessions created a few days ago didn't have the problem, but every new session I create does. What's going on here?

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only executed in login shells. The shells run by `screen` are not login shells. Put the code in `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.